# Google File Picker Dialog no iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up a file picker in my Google Apps Script for uploading reports. I've gotten it running using the tutorial provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#dialog.html) but I'm wondering if there is a way to launch the file picker as it's own dialog box? The code provided has it as an iframe in another modal dialog which I'm not crazy about the look of. I've provided copies of my script and html file below:

GAS code:

```
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('PickerHTML2.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaSyA5H6SiBu7r7OcZb1qEzgL6m-3YI6vYEeg';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {
      var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true);
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(uploadView)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is what it currently looks like. Again, I don't like having the iframe with the scrollbars is produces. So I'm looking for a way for it to be shown in as it's own dialog or without the scrollbars I guess.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean its own dialogue box? What environment are launching it in?

Comment: Its in a Google spreadsheet. The script is going to be run as an add on. I'll edit the post with a picture of what it looks like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Publish your own custom dialog as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Since your implementation is an Add-on, you can open the WebApp-dialog by clicking on a button from the Add-on sidebar.

Sample:

```
 <button id="portal" onclick="window.open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec', '_blank')" id="myButton" >open Picker in a custom WebApp dialog</button>
```

Whereby `https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec` is the deployment URL of your WebApp.

For the WebApp itself, replace

```js
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('PickerHTML2.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}
```

through

```js
function doGet() {
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('PickerHTML2.html')
   return html.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

and [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) the code as a WebApp.

Comment: So essentially have a different project just for the picker, deploy that as a webapp, and then launch that webapp from my add on?

Comment: The Webapp can also be published from the same project - whatever suits you best.